# How can I type hint python-polars dataframe row values?

Tags: python-typing, python-polars

I would like to be able to provide seamless type hints for a developer API that exposes a `polars.DataFrame` to the developer. Currently, in every IDE I've checked, if I do something like this...

```
tbl : polars.DataFrame[MyType] = polars.DataFrame([])
row1 = tbl.frame[1, :]
```

... `row1` is type-checked as `DataFrame`. Instead, I would like it to be type-checked as `MyType`. Is this possible? Or, will I need to rewrap this part of the API?

Comment: The polars [`DataFrame`](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/py-0.16.8/py-polars/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py#L164) is not generic. What makes you think you can use `__class_getitem__` on it in the first place? Also "linting" means picking up soft errors or bad style in your code. You mean static type checkers infer the type of `row1` as `DataFrame`.

Comment: I provided that syntax for succinctness; I'm aware it's not generic. Perhaps I used the term "linting" too liberally in the body of my question. Notably, however, it doesn't matter to me whether these are normal type hints or if the they are picked up by some other common static analysis system. Do you have any ideas besides me just rewrapping the `polars.DataFrame` in my own generic?

Comment: Now I understand your intention better. Since you cannot change the source and the class is not generic, the only way I can see is writing your own extension. But depending on what exactly you are aiming for, this may be far from trivial. The columns of a data frame can all have different, essentially arbitrary types. So I doubt the existing Python typing system will be sufficient to do this properly. I suppose you could compromise and just cover the simple case of the columns all being the same type.